# Link to parent site is not HTTPS in the sidebar/dropdown "Step 1: Draft your question" on any per-site Meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, per-site-meta, ssl

When [asking a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) here on Meta SE, the sidebar titled "Step 1: Draft your question" (which appears as a dropdown menu on mobile in the responsive design) has the following text:

> **Is your question about the Stack Exchange engine that powers the Stack Exchange [network](http://stackexchange.com/sites)?**

The hyperlink on "network" points to `http://stackexchange.com/sites`. Can this be changed to use HTTPS?

---

More generally, it seems (after checking on a bunch of Meta sites including [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)) that the hyperlink on "*SE parent site*" in

> **Is your question about the [*SE parent site*] community or website?**

always points to the HTTP version of the main site. It would be great if these could all be converted to HTTPS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two links are now fixed to use `https://`. And while doing so, I fixed over 100 other instances in the codebase as well.

> so h-t-t-p
> not a secure protocol
> h-t-t-p-s!

Comment: This must be the best haiku I've seen in a while here on MSE!

Comment: Yaakov, can you please take a look into this as well: [Change to HTTPS links in the /users?tab=moderators page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376439)?