# Change to HTTPS links in the /users?tab=moderators page

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl, users-page

In the `/users?tab=moderators` page of all SE sites (SO too), there is a link to the election page under each moderator's profile but the links are HTTP. Please change them to HTTPS.

<sub>Reasons to post this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341428 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1142248</sub>

Comment: Weirdly, this only happens on sites with elected moderators. Appointed moderators won't have a link usually, except on (I think) sites that graduated a long time ago. It's a (HTTP) link to a blog post, since there was no election for them. I don't know why it's inconsistent.

Comment: Rather than a bounty, getting things like this fixed would likely move forward faster if you flag to, politely, ask for a moderator to add the [tag:status-review] tag, if they can duplicate the bug. Adding the [tag:status-review] tag is how bugs, feature requests, and other issues requiring staff, enter Stack Exchange's internal ticketing system. If the question has never had the [tag:status-review] tag present, then it's likely that the issue isn't even on SE's radar. While having an internal ticket created is a first step, it certainly doesn't guarantee that the issue will be addressed.

Comment: @Makyen I guess I can do that but I am not sure. Mods might feel that I am being pushy.

Comment: @RandomPerson Yes, it could feel like you're being pushy, particularly if you do it shortly after posting the bug report. If you allow a bit of time to pass, a few/several days, but probably not weeks, from when the bug report was posted, a politely worded request in a flag seems reasonable for bug reports which aren't trivial. For bug reports which are critical (e.g. prevent critical portions of normal site operation), it's reasonable to flag immediately upon creation. For feature requests, it's better to wait a longer period and only flag if voting indicates substantial support.

Comment: @RandomPerson BTW: see "[What posts should be escalated to staff using \[status-review\], and how do I escalate them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/271271)" for a more detailed discussion about the [tag:status-review] tag, how it works, when it should be used, and how to get it added to a question.

Comment: @Makyen I flagged it and moderator added the tag :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Links to elections and appointments on the Users > Moderators page are now using the `https` protocol.

> So when did that mod
> win their election? A link!
> h-t-t-p-s!

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix Yaakov :)