# Link to per-site meta in the sidebar/dropdown "Step 1: Draft your question" is not HTTPS and has the old format meta.*.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, asking-questions, ssl

Similar to: [Link to parent site is not HTTPS in the sidebar/dropdown "Step 1: Draft your question" on any per-site Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376147/986753).

---

When asking a question on some SE sites, such as [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) the sidebar titled "Step 1: Draft your question" (which appears as a dropdown menu on mobile) has the following text:

> If your question is about this website, [**ask it on meta**](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/) instead.

The hyperlink points to http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/. Note that the link uses HTTP and also uses the [old format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/986753) `meta.*.stackexchange.com` for the meta site. Preferably, this URL should instead be https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/.

I checked several other sites and whenever the above text appears in the modal "Step 1: Draft your question" (such as [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask) and [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)), the hyperlink uses the old format for the respective meta site, and also uses HTTP instead of HTTPS. This text does not appear on all sites: it is omitted on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) and [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), for instance.

Also, note that I am specifically referring to the sidebar titled "Step 1: Draft your question". There is another sidebar titled "Helpful links" which has the text

> Ask questions about the site on [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com)

and — for instance, on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) — the hyperlink on the word "meta" points appropriately to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/. I haven't checked *all* the sites in the network, but I believe this aspect is uniform across all the sites.<sup>1</sup>

**Feature request:** Please change the hyperlink on the words "ask it on meta" to use HTTPS and to the format `https://*.meta.stackexchange.com/` whenever this text appears on the "Step 1: Draft your question" sidebar, when asking a question on any SE site.

---

<sup>1</sup> For the sake of completeness: except for [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) (naturally) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (where it is pushed to the sidebar titled "Have a non-programming question?", which is probably unique to that site).

Comment: As an aside: I noticed a few other site-specific instances of links using HTTP instead of HTTPS in the modals — on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask) and [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), to be specific — but those were probably introduced when the text was tweaked as decided by the respective communities, and so I felt that they should be raised separately on their respective metas, if needed...