# Link to stackexchange.com is not HTTPS under the default "community-specific" close reason on per-site metas

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, per-site-meta, ssl

There is a default close reason available on per-site metas under "Needs improvement → A community-specific reason" that has a link to `stackexchange.com` that is not HTTPS. For instance, on Mathematics Meta, this text reads:

> This question does not appear to be about Mathematics Stack Exchange or the software that powers the Stack Exchange [network](http://stackexchange.com/sites) within the scope defined in the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

The first link, over the text "network", points to `http://stackexchange.com/sites`. On all the per-site metas that I checked, I found that this close reason has this HTTP link (though Meta SE is an exception). So, I assume that this is the case on all per-site metas.

Additionally, on some sites such as Mathematics Meta and Meta Stack Overflow that use custom community-specific close reasons, I found that the ["Blatantly off-topic" flag reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300056/why-are-there-two-different-close-reasons-for-questions-that-arent-about-the-si) also has a HTTP link to `stackexchange.com`. For instance, on Mathematics Meta, this text reads:

> ###### Blatantly off-topic
>
> This question has nothing to do with Mathematics Stack Exchange or the software that powers the Stack Exchange [network](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

Again, the link over the text "network" points to `http://stackexchange.com/sites` (and again, Meta SE seems to be an exception).

Can these links please be updated to use HTTPS?

Comment: Related:  [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time). (From March 2017.)

Comment: @W.O. yeah, naturally they missed some spots. Surely there are more.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Yes, for instance: [Link to per-site meta in the sidebar/dropdown "Step 1: Draft your question" is not HTTPS and has the old format meta.*.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377064/986753)